# The Vectors in $v=f\lambda$

Tags: waves, vectors

We are learning about waves in physics and I was just wondering what are the vectors and what are the scalars in this function:$$v=f\lambda$$

I know the velocity $v$ is a vector so that means that: either the frequency is a vector and the wavelength is scalar or vice-versa. Personally, I think the wavelength must be the vector. So what are the scalar and vector quantities in this relationship?

Comment: $v$ is speed not velocity.

Comment: Yet again, we have problems with notation of the magnitude of a vector.  More properly, $|\vec{v}| = f\lambda$, but all that notation is usually dropped for simplicity, leaving it up to the reader to understand what is meant from the context of the formula.  This problem is especially acute when the simplified notation is used in intro textbooks.   Only a few bother to be more explicitly correct.  The answer by @Farcher considers the issue in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question and the answers which have been given show that the $v$ in your equation should be called the magnitude of the velocity or just the speed of the wave.  The mixing of the terms speed and velocity happens all the time.

Now there is an equation for wave velocity but in comes about in a somewhat convoluted way.

Suppose that you produced some ripples on a pond.  To illustrate the ripples you might draw something like this:

[image]

Or would you?

Usually when you see such diagrams the ripples are drawn as concentric equally spaced circles.
Now those lines are called **wave fronts** and indicate positions where all the particles are oscillating in phase with one another.

For convenience a conventional diagram usually only shows wave fronts which are spaced by one wavelength $\lambda$, shown in red in the diagram.

Wave fronts move in a direction which is perpendicular to the wave front.  This is the same direction as the direction of wave motion and this is the direction of the the wave velocity $\vec v$.  In fact this is the phase velocity as it is to do with the motion of particles which are all in phase with one another.

For more advanced work a parameter called wave number $\vec k$ is introduced which is defined as follows:
It has a magnitude of $\frac {2 \pi}{\lambda}$ and a direction which is perpendicular to the wave fronts.

The connection between the velocity and the wavenumber is that their dot product is equal to  $\omega = 2 \pi f$ where $f$ is the frequency of the wave.

So you have $\vec v \cdot \vec k = \omega \Rightarrow v = f \lambda$ and this relationship gives you the magnitude of the velocity of a wave or its speed.

So in more advanced work it is the parameter $\vec k$ which incorporates information about the direction of motion of a wave

Answer (score 0):

Since the wavelength is the *distance*
between the two consecutive crests or troughs
it isn't a vector quantity. It is scalar.

Simillarly, Frequency is a scalar quantity, since it just number of crest and trough per second. How can such number have direction.