# phase velocity versus instantaneous velocity

Tags: waves

I'm trying to understand the relationship between phase velocity and instantaneous velocity in relation to the vector direction. This still isn't clear to me: [Wave fronts move in a direction which is perpendicular to the wave front. This is the same direction as the direction of wave motion and this is the direction of the the wave velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234278/the-vectors-in-v-f-lambda).

Sure, perpendicular from a 2D aerial perspective, I get that. But what if I cut a slice along the perpendicular (from the image in the link) and looked at a profile view
[image: profile view of wave]
where the "perpendicular" from the aerial perspective in the link, is given by the purple arrow. My wave front (which extends into the page), I've defined at the red dot. The green arrow is the surface normal and the blue is the tangent.

If this is a progressive wave, then the direction of the instantaneous velocity will only align (parallel) with the purple arrow if the wave front is defined at the crest. So, if I define the wave front at the red dot shown (assuming I can) then what is the relationship between phase and instantaneous velocity?

Comment: Assuming it's progressing in the x-direction, would the purple arrow be $k_x$ ? If I wanted to find the relationship between the two would I then take the dot product of the instantaneous velocity to get the angular frequency? I believe that's what @Farcher is saying in the link?

Comment: So if the wave front was defined at the progressive node (where the instantaneous velocity is purely vertical) the dot product would be zero, meaning the angular frequency is zero?

Comment: Following the concept of conservation of waves (Whitham), my wave flux $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}$ would be zero, which makes sense considering the instantaneous velocity is purely vertical?

Comment: I should note too that I'm considering periodic linear waves at the moment. I'm just trying to get a geometric interpretation of magnitudes and directions associated with phase, wavenumber, and angular frequency. If so, I also want to see how I can relate them to velocity.

Comment: Wavefront is a set of points with the same phase. Not a single point.

Comment: @ApoorvKhurasia It's a profile image...the wave front would extend into the page.

Comment: I mean it should be a surface in 3-D. A surface in 3 dimensions has a well defined perpendicular.

Comment: Interesting....so if I traced out the wave front in my 2D image, it would be a curve, say along the wave face? That would mean that my instantaneous velocities can vary, but their variations must be in phase? Is that the right idea?

Comment: @ApoorvKhurasia Also, when you say "A surface in 3 dimensions has a well defined perpendicular" are you referring to the surface normals?

Comment: Yes jack. I mean surface normals and yes to previous question as well. Let's move to a chat if you have more questions on this because the comment thread is getting longer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35632/discussion-between-thatsrightjack-and-apoorv-khurasia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard diagram that you see in a text book to illustrate a wave is shown below.  It is called a wave profile and you can liken it to a photograph of the wave taken at one instant of time.
The diagram below shows two such photographs taken at a time $t$ and a later time $t+\Delta t$.

[image]

Assume that it is a transverse wave travelling in the positive x-direction..
Particles at $A, C, E$ and $G$ are instantaneously at rest.
Particles at $B$ and $F$ have a maximum instantaneous velocity in the $+z$ direction and particles at $D$ and $H$ have a maximum instantaneous velocity in the $-z$ direction.

This is a wave travelling from left to right and the crest of the wave at $A$ travels a distance $\Delta x$ to get to position $A^\prime$ in a time $\Delta t$ and so has a velocity of $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ to the right.
This is the phase velocity of the wave and also the instantaneous velocity of the wave (but **not** the particles in the medium).

Note that the working out of the phase velocity could have been done by choosing any point on the graph at time $t$ and measuring the distance moved by the wave to the corresponding same phase point at a time $t+\Delta t$ where again the distance travelled would have been $\Delta x$.

A wave travels one wavelength $\lambda$ in a one period of one oscillation of a particle $T$ so the phase speed is $\frac{\lambda}{T} = \lambda f$ where $f$ is the frequency of the wave.

A difficulty arise when one wants to show a wavefront because the screen is two dimensional but the required graph is three dimensional.

So here is my attempt at showing a plane wave in three dimensions

[image]

You will note that in the $y=0$ plane the graph is the same as the one drawn above at time $t$.

$Aa$ is a wavefront (green) which happens to be a crest of the wave.  The green arrows, which are at right angles to the wave front, shown the direction of the wave velocity.  Because it is the crest of the wave the instantaneous velocity of the particles along the wavefront is zero.

$Mm$ is another wavefront with the direction of the wave velocity shown (red arrows) and is the same as that for wavefront $Aa$.  The particle velocities are shown with a blue arrow and are at right angles to the direction of the wave velocity because it is a transverse wave.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Just for further clarification, would "K", in the image above, be the vector or does it represent the x-component "Kx"? Same question for the blue arrow, the particle velocity...is it the velocity vector, or the z-component, say "Uz"? Also, wouldn't point "A" have a maximum velocity in the x direction?

Comment: Perhaps I should have not used k as it might cause confusion with the wave number.  k is just part of a label for the wavefront Kk.  I have now changed the label for that wave front to $Mm$ to avoid any confusion.  The blue arrow is the velocity vector for the particle in the medium through which the wave travels. The **particle** velocity at $A$ is 0.  The particle is executing shm & has reached the amplitude of the motion & has stopped ready to start moving down. Think about the wave a little later in time; where there was a crest there will be a displacement less than that at the crest.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The book I was referencing was using cos harmonic motion, so I guess that would explain my miss understanding with the velocity at point A. In the profile image you've drawn above, at time t+dt, all points moved parallel to the x-axis. So that would mean the vector wave number, k, points in the x-direction, hence the direction of the phase velocity. The front is perpendicular to the vector K.

Comment: That being said, if point "A" at time t+dt, was say "shifted down the trough", the vector wave number would have an angle with the x-axis? Would this indicate a phase shift due to a non constant phase speed? Would the wave front still be perpendicular with the vector wave number (which is now at an angle)? The wave would still be traveling to the right though? Sorry for all the questions. You've been very helpful though!

Comment: The wave velocity vectors are in the same direction as the k vectors.  So your wavefront $Mm$ is moving in the positive x direction as is the wave front $Aa$.  The k vector is always parallel to the x axis.

Comment: If you could comment I my last response, I will consider this closed. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: I thought that I have answered all your questions?  The k vector is always perpendicular to the wavefront and in this example the k vector is parallel to the x axis.

Comment: "That being said, if point "A" at time t+dt, was say "shifted down the trough", the vector wave number would have an angle with the x-axis? Would this indicate a phase shift due to a non constant phase speed? Would the wave front still be perpendicular with the vector wave number (which is now at an angle)? The wave would still be traveling to the right though? Sorry for all the questions. You've been very helpful though!"

Comment: No.  Look at my first diagram.  The wavefront which was the crest still stay the crest a little later in time.  So in the bottom diagram to blinked and looked at the wave again you wound have found that the crest, and the wavefront on top of it, has moved to the right with the crest still being of the same height (z) as before.